# React reduce and replace on nested object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm mapping data from a JSON to a React component, where part of the strings from the JSON are replaced by values from Context. This works perfectly for JSON that only has a single level.

**This works:**

```
/* JSON */
const data = {
  "content":[
    "#number# Tips to Get #goal#",
    "Your Search For #goal# Ends Here"
  ]
}

const parameters = useContext(ParameterContext)
  const {
    audience,
    goal,
    number
  } = parameters;

const content = data.content;

const listItems = content.map(
  (result, index) => 
  <li key={index}>{Object.keys(parameters).reduce((res, key) => 
    res.replace(`#${key}#`, parameters[key]), result)}</li>
);

...

return (
  <ul>
    {listItems}
  </ul>
)
```

However, when I introduce another level of nesting to my JSON data, the `.map()` function breaks. For example:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "text" : "#number# Tips to Get #goal#",
      "types" : [ "email"]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Your Search For #goal# Ends Here",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to parse that results in `TypeError: res.replace is not a function`. Now, I suspect that's because the target text strings are now inside another array, but I can't figure out how to reach them in my `map()` function.

How would I fix the `map()` function to read the text strings in the update JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    const listItems = content.map((result, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
        {Object.keys(parameters).reduce((res, key) => {
            return res.replace(`#${key}#`, parameters[key]);
        }, result.text)} //result -> result.text
    </li>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce to accrue the li elements in an array. Modify the text property by using the values of the object keys

```js
const obj = {
  "content": [{
      "text": "#number# Tips to Get #goal#",
      "types": ["email"]
    },
    {
      "text": "Your Search For #goal# Ends Here",
      "types": ["ad", "email"]
    }
  ]
}


const parameters = {
  audience: 'audience1',
  goal: 'goal1',
  number: 'number1'
}

const keys = Object.keys(parameters)

const listItems = obj.content.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    x.text = x.text.replace(`#${key}#`, parameters[key])
  })
  acc.push(`<li key=${i}> ${x.text}</li>`);
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(listItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the text inside of the object you can use destructuring.

```
const listItems = content.map(({ text }, index) => (
  <li key={index}>
    {Object.keys(parameters).reduce(
      (res, key) => res.replace(`#${key}#`, parameters[key]),
      text
    )}
  </li>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private menu: Object = {
  "content": [
    {
      "text" : "#number# Tips to Get #goal#",
      "types" : [ "email"]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Your Search For #goal# Ends Here",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    }
  ]
};

public buildMenu():void
{
    let html: string  = '<ul>';
    this.menu.forEach( (menuItems) => html += buildMenuSubMenu(menuItem) );
    html += '</ul>'
}

private buildMenuSubMenu(menuItem): string
{
    let html: string = null;

    html += `<li><a href='${menuItem[types][0]}'>${menuItem[text]}</a>`;

    if (menuItem.lenght)
    {
        html += '<ul>';
        menuItem.forEach( (child) => html += buildMenuSubMenu(child) );
        html += '</ul>';
    }

    html += '<li>';

    return html;
}
```